# JAX-RS How to serialise JSON objects that are embedded within a common wrapper object and deserialise without the wrapper

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson, jax-rs

I intend to send JSON data to my JAX-RS endpoints like so:

`POST /myendpoint`

```
{
  "field1": "something",
  "field2": "something else",
  "field3": 12345
}
```

Then when I retrieve an object I want it contained in a common wrapper:

`GET /myendpoint`

```
{
  "type": "MyEndpoint"
  "items": [
    {
      "item":     {
        "id": 1,
        "field1": "something",
        "field2": "something else",
        "field3": 12345
      },
      "link": "https://api.site.com/myendpoint/1"
    },
    {
      "item":     {
        "id": 2,
        "field1": "different",
        "field2": "different else",
        "field3": 67890
      },
      "link": "https://api.site.com/myendpoint/2"
    }
  ],
  "page_size": 10,
  "page": 1,
  "total": 2,
  "message": ""
}
```

And

`GET /myendpoint/2`

```
{
  "type": "MyEndpoint"
  "items": [
    {
      "item":     {
        "id": 2,
        "field1": "different",
        "field2": "different else",
        "field3": 67890
      },
      "link": "https://api.site.com/myendpoint/2"
    }
  ],
  "page_size": 10,
  "page": 1,
  "total": 1,
  "message": ""
}
```

I am starting to use Jackson FasterXML in Jersey for automatic serialisation/deserialisation, ie:

```
@Provider
public class JsonObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JsonObjectMapperProvider() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(final Class<?> type) {
        return objectMapper;
    }

}
```

And then in the resources:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void createMyEndpoint(MyEndpoint myEndpoint) {
    myEndpointDao.create(myEndpoint);
    // ...
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<MyEndpoint> createMyEndpoint() {
    // I'm not actually sure how to do this one yet!! but I include it for completeness
    return myEndpointDao.getAll();
}

@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public MyEndpoint createMyEndpoint(@PathParam("{id}") id) {
    return myEndpointDao.read(id);
}
```

This would work for MyEndpoint objects that aren't contained in the wrapper but how would I include the wrapper? Or is there an altogether better way to do this?

The schema for the JSON isn't set in stone, if something else makes more sense then I'm all ears.

Comment: which version of jax-rs, 2.0?

Comment: Yes JAX-RS 2.0, I'm using Jersey 2.25.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I write few suggestion I have in mind reading your question:

1. return always something from your methods, even if you're handling a POST method. This will make the caller aware of request status.
2. instead of return your model objects, I think is better if your methods return always an object `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`
3. if you're worried about the serialization (I mean the use of the wrapper) just use the `Response` object to serialize your response. For example for a success response use: `Response.ok().entity(yourReturnObject).build()`, this will care of the serialization part almost transparently (you don't need to handle the objectMapper).

This could be a trivial example of a method:

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@Produces({ "application/json" })
public Response createMyEndpoint(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    try {
        return Response.ok().entity(myEndpointDao.read(id)).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       Response.status(500).entity(e.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

I also suggest, to make you're life simpler, have a look at [swagger](http://swagger.io/).

Comment: I completely misread your answer initially; I wrongly assumed that by returning Response I was throwing away the auto JSON serialization, leaving me blind the fact that (you even stated) that I wasn't. I continued to research and came to this same conclusion. Upon re-reading your answer I realise that the solution was here all along, also the fact that I use a wrapper POJO is irrelevant as Jackson handles this seamlessly if using generics e.g `MyWrapper<MyType> wrapper = new MyWrapper<>();` then `return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).entity(wrapper).build();`.

Comment: At least now I am confident and have convinced myself that this is the correct way to proceed, which is always good :)

Comment: @Neilos pleased and satisfied you found my answer correct ;)